# Looping through worksheets to convert range into table

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I am trying to create a looping procedure that goes through multiple worksheets and converts the data into a table. I think my code keeps breaking because obviously each array can only have one instance of "Table1". I have a couple of questions:

1: is there a way to dynamically name each table. Ex: set the name of the table to the worksheet title?

2: how can i create error handling code that exits the sub routine if there is already an existing table. EX. I have already run this on my existing workbook, but added a new sheet with raw data and still need to convert it to a table.

Here is what I have so far, any and all help is appreciated (new to VBA)

```
Sub newTables()


' newTables Macro
' T
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+T

Dim rngSelectionRange As Range
Set rngSelectionRange = ActiveSheet.Range(Selection.Address)

For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count

    Worksheets(i).Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    'where it breaks
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, rngSelectionRange, , xlYes).Name = "Table1"
    'Range("Table1[#All]").Select
    'ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").TableStyle = "TableStyleLight2"
    'ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Employ").Name = "Employee_Data"
    If ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Count > 1 Then
    End If

Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is basically what you want. You can check if a range has a ListObject, which is handy here:

```
Sub AddTablesIfNone()
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        With ws
            If .UsedRange.ListObject Is Nothing Then
                .ListObjects.Add SourceType:=xlSrcRange, Source:=.UsedRange, xllistobjecthasHeaders:=xlYes
            End If
        End With
    Next ws
    End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! that seemed to work pretty well, but it doesn't select exactly where the data is (it just goes down a random number of rows. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: There surely is. How would you describe the limits of your data range?

Comment: My end goal is to paste a selection in a new row in each table in each worksheet, the range needs dynamic ex: xldown xlright type thing.

Comment: You should be able to search for that kind of dynamic thing and take a shot at it. Then simply substitute that range for the `UsedRange` part of the code I gave you. Without a more detailed description or picture of your data that's what I can tell you. Except for one thing ... you're better off with an xlUp/XlLeft type of thing as you'll see when you do some research. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, rngSelectionRange, , xlYes).Name = "Table" & i
```

This will name the first table in the loop `Table1`, then `Table2`, etc.

Or if you want the worksheet's name, replace `"Table" & i` with: `Worksheets(i).Name`, though perhaps you want to add a prefix of say, "Table" just to avoid confusion.

Comment: Thanks! for some reason though after it goes through the first sheet, it gets to the second and gives a "selection of range class failed". any ideas?

Comment: You're only setting the `rngSelectionRange` for the first sheet but using it each time you define the table (it's the second parameter) - I think you should be using just what you have selected, i.e. `Selection`?